# Validate a string is only digits and only a certain length

Tags: c++, string, int

So I have an issue.

I need to take a string (I cannot have it as an int, it has to be defined as a string) and inside of the set method, I have to validate that the number is either 9 or 13 digits long and contains only digits.

I can validate the length using str.length() but I cannot get it to validate that the input only contains digits.

Here is my current code:

```
void Book::setISBN(string ISBN) 
{

//validate the length here  ALSO NEED TO VALIDATE ITS A NUMBER

if (ISBN.length() >= 9 && ISBN.length() <= 13) {

    this->ISBN = ISBN;
}
else {
    this->ISBN = '0';
}
}
```

This is the code which it will pull the information:

```
Book b = Book();
b.setISBN("23");
b.setAuthor("R.L. Stine");
b.setTitle("Goosebumps");
b.setPrice(25.00);

Book b2 = Book("thisisshith", "Stephen King", "IT", 20.32);
```

The first part, b works as the setISBN("23") will return with a zero but the b2 "thisisshith" returns just like that. I need it to return as 0 as well. If it was a set of digits between 9-13 in length then it would return correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

*I have tried isdigit() but says it cannot convert between a string and int.*

Comment: "*either 9 or 13 digits long*" and "*digits between 9-13 in length*" are contradictory requirements.  Which one do you actually need?  EXACTLY 9 or 13 digits, or BETWEEN 9 and 13 digits?

Comment: I literally quoted the assignment there. So I am going to assume either 9 digits or 13 digits. However, as I stated, the length is not what I am needing, I am needing to be able to validate they are ONLY numerical, non-alphabetical.

Comment: Why do you split the checksum from the ISBN-10, but not from the ISBN-13?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: ISBNs are either old-style ISBN-10 (checksum is last, 0 to 9 or X), or new style ISBN-13 (checksum is last, 0 to 9). The former can be mapped to the latter. [See wikipedia on ISBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number).

Comment: The assignment states for it to be 9 or 13.  So that's what I have to deal with

Comment: Well, consider pointing out the error in the assignment then. And should you normalize them to ISBN-13 or not? If you do, you could store them into a 64-bit integer instead of a string. That might be overkill though.

Comment: It's mainly an assignment to understand set/get, and constructors so i dont think she cares about it actually being a legit item

Comment: Well, after the assignment is over, consider asking on [codereview.se] how to improve it.

Comment: This honestly not something I care to much about I just want the 100 on the assignment. I already program in c# n python I'm just aiming for an A in this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Book` constructor, make sure it is calling `setISBN()` and not setting `this->ISBN` directly:

```
Book::Book(string ISBN, ...) {
    //this->ISBN = ISBN;
    this->setISBN(ISBN);
    ...
}
```

Then, inside of `setISBN()`, you can do something like this:

```
void Book::setISBN(string ISBN) 
{
    if (((ISBN.length() == 9) || (ISBN.length() == 13)) &&
        (ISBN.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == string::npos))
    {
        this->ISBN = ISBN;
    }
    else
    {
        this->ISBN = '0';
    }
}
```

If you want to use `isdigit()` instead, you will need a loop that checks each individual `char` in the string.  You can either do that manually:

```
#include <cctype>

void Book::setISBN(string ISBN) 
{
    if ((ISBN.length() == 9) || (ISBN.length() == 13))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ISBN.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (!isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ISBN[i])))
            {
                this->ISBN = '0';
                return;
            }
        }
        this->ISBN = ISBN;
    }
    else
    {
        this->ISBN = '0';
    }
}
```

Or, you can use standard search algorithms, like `std::find()` or `std::all_of()`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

void Book::setISBN(string ISBN) 
{
    if (((ISBN.length() == 9) || (ISBN.length() == 13)) &&
        (std::find(ISBN.begin(), ISBN.end(), [](char ch){ return !isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)); }) == ISBN.end()))
    {
        this->ISBN = ISBN;
    }
    else
    {
        this->ISBN = '0';
    }
}
```

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

void Book::setISBN(string ISBN) 
{
    if (((ISBN.length() == 9) || (ISBN.length() == 13)) &&
        std::all_of(ISBN.begin(), ISBN.end(), [](char ch)->bool { return isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)); }))
    {
        this->ISBN = ISBN;
    }
    else
    {
        this->ISBN = '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run this, it still does not convert the needed items to a 0, it still displays the "thisisshith"

Comment: Make sure your constructor set ISBN using the method `setISBN` or that in the constructor you do similar check to the ISBN.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

There is also a part in the code that is:

```
Book::Book(string ISBN, string author, string title, double price) {
this->ISBN = ISBN;
this->author = author;
this->title = title;
this->price = price;`
```

I added this to the end of that line:

```
    if ((ISBN.length() == 9) || (ISBN.length() == 13) &&
    ISBN.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == string::npos)
{
    this->ISBN = ISBN;
}
else {
    this->ISBN = '0';
}
```

This fixes what I need fixed. Thanks!

Comment: A better solution would be to make that constructor call `setISBN()` instead, so your validations are all in one place: `Book::Book(string ISBN, ...) { this->setISBN(ISBN); ... }`